# How do you build PoDoFo on iOS with Openssl support?

Tags: ios, iphone, openssl, podofo

I have a project which uses PoDoFo for digitally signing PDF so I am trying to integrate [CTOpenSSLWrapper](https://github.com/ebf/CTOpenSSLWrapper) into a single project which uses both PoDoFo and OpenSSL libraries. But when i try to build it, iam getting issues with linking:

[image]

The same error repeats with `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7` if I try to run on device.

I have cross-checked every thing:

1. header search paths
2. library search paths
3. Buildphases->compile sources for any missing .m files

But i still have the same issue.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Be careful of that version of OpenSSL with `CTOpenSSLWrapper`. Its OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012. 1.0.1h is the latest, and it fixes a few serious vulnerabilities. Also, the fat library is missing ARM64.

Answer (score 0):

> I have cross-checked every thing:
>
> ```
>  1. header search paths
>  2. library search paths
>  3. Buildphases->compile sources for any missing .m files
> ```

It appears you are *not* including the library (only providing the library search path).

Here's what a typical library include looks like for me. Its for OpenSSL, but the same will apply to PoDoFo. In the example below, OpenSSL built for iOS is located in `/usr/local/ssl/ios`. Headers are located in is located in `/usr/local/ssl/ios/include/openssl`, and libraries are located in `/usr/local/ssl/ios/lib`.

**Paths**:

[image]

**Library**:

[image]

---

If you still have linker errors *after* adding the library, then perform the following to ensure you library has the architectures you need. I'm using OpenSSL as an example, you should use the PoDoFo library's name.

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libcrypto.a
```

You should see something like:

```
Architectures in the fat file: libcrypto.a are: armv7 armv7s arm64 i386
```

---

If you need an OpenSSL built for iOS, then try this GitHub: [noloader/openssl-1.0.1h-ios](https://github.com/noloader/openssl-1.0.1h-ios). Its a fat library, and has all the architectures you might need for iOS.

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. I have verified the things that you have specified but i'm still getting the same issue.
Here is the **[Sample project](https://github.com/Jagadeeshwar-Reddy/podofo_iOS_sample)** that i'm working on, if you could take a look in to it and point out what was the problem, it would be good.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have those libraries available on my machine. So I would get a slew of different errors.

Comment: The libraries are actually embedded in the sample project itself. I think you will not any errors related to missing libraries.